# Problem with flask and Markdown i can't add multiple exstensions

Tags: python, flask, markdown

The problem is that I want to add multiple extensions to Markdown so I can do this

```
Markdown(app, extensions=['tables'])
```

but i can't do this one

```
Markdown(app, extensions=[('tables','fenced_code')])
```

giving an error like:

> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/markdown/core.py",
>   line 137, in registerExtensions Extension.**module**,
>   Extension.**name** TypeError: Extension "builtins.tuple" must be of
>   type: "markdown.extensions.Extension"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't put them in a tuple. I believe just adding another extension to the list of extensions should be enough, like so:

```
Markdown(app, extensions=['tables','fenced_code'])
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [source](https://github.com/Python-Markdown/markdown/blob/890314909ad21547f14f298e159fd61bed757d50/markdown/core.py#L58) of the `Markdown` class, the `extensions` kwarg accepts a list of extensions, so you should just pass the extension names(as strings) in a list. The instances of the list can be of type `markdown.extension.Extension` or 'string'. Since, you are passing a tuple, it leads to the error.

```
#code
extensions=['tables','fenced_code']
```

Comment: a) It points to the source code to verify and b) it explains why OP is getting the error.

Comment: I'm new to SO, and just want to learn more. Wouldn't it be more appropriate to just edit my answer to include that, though? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Hopefully our answers are helpful to the OP